# Can the "Aggregations" tab in MongoDB Compass alter original documents?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

Is there a risk of unintended modification to original documents when using the "Aggregations" tab in [MongoDB Compass](https://www.mongodb.com/products/compass)? I want to ensure that my data remains unchanged and intact throughout the aggregation process.

*MongoDB Compass for Mac, version 1.38.0*

[image: MongoDB Compass tabs]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [official docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/) it says:

> Aggregation pipelines run with the `db.collection.aggregate()` method do not modify documents in a collection, unless the pipeline contains a `$merge` or `$out`stage.

Also since MongoDB 4.2 you can use aggregations pipeline into update queries, but that's not the point.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a risk.

If you use `$merge` stage, then existing data is updated.

Or if you use `$out` stage, which creates a new collection and **replaces** an existing collection entirely.

If you want to ensure that data is not modified, then grant privileges accordingly to the user, see [Built-In Roles](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/reference/built-in-roles/)